# Java SWT: Displaying a Grid over an image

Tags: java, image, image-processing, swt

I need to do the following using Java SWT:

1. Display a list of Pixels as an Image
2. Allow the user to select a subset of Pixels
3. Display a Grid over the image as a guide for the user.  The Image still needs to handle mouse events

1) and 2) are straightforward, however I don't know how to achieve 3).
Reading up on SWT, I do not see a way to put a Transparent Overlay over an image.  Is this possible?  Is there another method?

Comment: Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: @Baz  Just got back to you there.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I wonder why this was down-voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just draw the grid on top of the `Image`. Set `GG#setAlpha(int)` to a low value to make the lines transparent. This will not interfere with mouse events:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Stackoverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Image image = new Image(display, "baz.png");

    Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            GC gc = event.gc;

            gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

            gc.setAlpha(30);

            int interval = image.getBounds().height;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int y = (int) Math.floor(i * (interval / 10.0));

                gc.drawLine(0, y, image.getBounds().width, y);
            }


            interval = image.getBounds().width;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int x = (int) Math.floor(i * (interval / 10.0));

                gc.drawLine(x, 0, x, image.getBounds().width);
            }

            gc.setAlpha(255);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
    image.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Sounds good - I'll try that.  This was my first instinct, although folks were suggesting an overlay.